# Why are ODFM pilot tones repeated?

Tags: digital-communication

Why are pilot tones repeated so much in OFDM?

I understand the pilot tones are used for synchronization, ensuring the phase of an OFDM signal is correct. It's for fine grained control after using the pre cylicguards to determine the rough start of a signal.

My best guess for repeating pilot tones is redundancy in case there's noise that distorts a pilot tone(s).

I'm not sure what else there would be? As with my understanding, assuming the signal was received perfectly, one pilot tone would work? As you will know the signal is in phase, once the pilot tone amplitude is correct?

Or is it possible to somehow get the phrase for the pilot tone correct but the signal incorrect?

Thanks